# TInyXML++ Premake with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I tried to compile TinyXML++(or TICPP) using premake4 with these settings: "premake4 vs2010 [--unicode] [--ticpp-shared] [--dynamic-runtime]". It compiles the .libs but I can't compile TiCPP.vcxproj because the compiler says "Unable to start program c:\ticpp\lib\ticpp.lib. This file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary file." Anyone got a clue how to make this work? Oh and one more thing, why does Windows ask me if I want to open a .vcxproj with Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 10? How do I make it so that it only picks one, and what's the difference. I tried the first answer, but it didn't work.

Comment: `"Unable to start program c:\ticpp\lib\ticpp.lib. This file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary file."` this sounds like it compiles just fine but you're trying to execute a library after building.

Answer (score 1):

Download last version of premake, it does support VS2010

I have compiled tinyXML++ using it, by executing:

premake4 vs2010

it does generate valid sln and vcxproj files.

Answer (score 0):

From [oolua build instructions](http://code.google.com/p/oolua/wiki/Building)

> Visual Studio 2010 (vs10) is not currently supported by premake yet if you have vs10 installed you can run the following command, it will generate vs9 projects and update them using the vs10 command line tool.
>
> ```
> premake4 vs2010
> ```
>
> As vs10 adds files which have not been created directly by premake, a specific clean operation has been added to the premake script.
>
> ```
> premake4 cleanVS10
> ```
>
> Scripts to build a local install, build and run unit test etc. have been added for vs10 in the script directory.

Notes:
* oolua's premake4 script may not be the same as yours.
* VS2010 support is borked in premake.  Current workaround is to make a 2008 project and make VS2010 convert it for you.

Comment: Neither solutions worked, because the script is different and when I convert, it doesn't let me create due to the same error.